# How to insert the keys and values of python dict in mysql using python

Tags: python, mysql, dictionary, insert, executemany

I have a python dict like this:

```
my_dict = {'find': ['http://time.com', 'http://find.com'], 'time': ['http://any.com', 'http://www.tim.com', 'http://mine.in']...}
```

I want to insert `keys` and `values` of dictionary `my_dict` in two different columns of a mysql table. The columns names are `term` and `urls` respectively. I have three columns for now: `id`, `term`, `urls` and **I want to insert each keys and values pairs in different rows.**

I want to store the links in `urls` as seperated by commas. The website links in the values of my_dict must be stored seperated by commas like `http://time.com, http://mine.com.`
I tried to insert in the following manner

```
for i in my_dict.items():   
    keys = i[0]
    values = i[1]
    sql = """INSERT INTO index_table (term, urls) VALUES (%s, %s)"""
    cursor.execute(sql, (keys, values))
```

But it shows the following error:

```
(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '))' at line 1")
```

Comment: Did you check that the SQL you're producing is what you expect?

Comment: why you do not want to use some kind of ORM toolkits? `sqlalchemy` for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your values in this instance are lists which you are attempting to pass to the SQL query and that is causing you issues.

If you want a separate record for each url in the values section (assuming you are going to always have a list for the values portion)

```
for i in my_dict.items():
    term = i[0]
    for url in i[1]:
        sql = """INSERT INTO index_table (term, urls) VALUES (%s, %s)"""
        cursor.execute(sql, (term, url))
```

Or if you want to store the urls together in one record, you would need to pickle the list or convert to a format like json. Would require you to handle the data appropriately when pulling the data out from the database

```
import json
for i in my_dict.items():
    term = i[0]
    urls = json.dumps(i[1])
    sql = """INSERT INTO index_table (term, urls) VALUES (%s, %s)"""
    cursor.execute(sql, (term, urls))
```

To store the urls in comma separated format instead;

```
for i in my_dict.items():
    term = i[0]
    urls = ', '.join(i[1])
    sql = """INSERT INTO index_table (term, urls) VALUES (%s, %s)"""
    cursor.execute(sql, (term, urls))
```

Comment: Oh no, I am sorry, I want to store the links in urls as seperated by commas, means I want to remove the square and double inverted commas,

Comment: just updated the answer to show storing the urls separated by comma